# почему set не работает с списком

Tags: python, list, set

почему `set` не работает для `list`

```
set([[0], [0]])
```

выкидывает ошибку:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

перевел на русский:

```
TypeError: нехешируемый тип: 'список'
```

понятнее не стало. что означает и как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваши списки не очень длинные, то "исправить" можно, превратив внутренние списки в кортежи - кортежи уже хэшируемы, поскольку они неизменяемые объекты, в отличие от списков:

```
list_of_lists = [[0], [0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
print(set(map(tuple, list_of_lists)))
```

Вывод:

```
{(0,), (0, 1), (0, 1, 2), (1, 2)}
```

А также покажу обратное преобразование кортежей в списки, если они вам потом всё-таки понадобятся:

```
set_of_tuples = set(map(tuple, list_of_lists))
print(list(map(list, set_of_tuples)))
```

На выходе:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0], [0, 1], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

потому что по каждому элементу множество `set` вычисляет некоторое число (условно) и ставит в соответствие этому числу элемент множества

простой пример - текст и md5 от текста или crc32 от текста (почитайте про хэш-суммы)

в результате очень быстро можно осуществлять поиск и т.д., то с чем и работает множество как список уникальных элементов

а теперь скажите как именно подсчитать хэш от списка?

поскольку множество этого не умеет, то и соответственно не допускает размещения таких элементов

Comment: спасибо, понял. но как все таки заставить `set` работать с `list`?

Comment: превратить в константные объекты, как и советует CrazyElf

Comment: Но при этом можно сделать `class List(list): __hash__ = lambda self: 0` и такой список уже можно добавить в set)

Comment: На самом деле думаю нет никакой проблемы посчитать hash для списка так же, как это делается для кортежа. Скорее всего создатели питона сознательно не стали давать такую возможность, чтобы не поощрять применение неподходящих типов для словарей и множеств.